# Unsure of graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

Are the following sets of graphs isomorphic? I believe the first set (the rooted trees) are, and with the second set (the free trees), I notice that both trees have 2 vertices with degree 3, one with degree two, and 4 with degree one, but my assignment says to "re-label one of the trees to show the one to one correspondence between the vertices" and I'm not quite sure how to go about that for either pair. Any help would be much appreciated.

Rooted Trees

[image]

Free Trees

[image]

Comment: The first pair is already labelled to show an isomorphism, assuming that these are not being considered as ordered trees.

Answer (score 2):

In the left free tree, the two vertices of degree $3$ are not connected by a single edge, and in the right free tree they are. This difference implies there is no isomorphism between the two free trees.